# Add 15 minutes to current time then determine whether new time went past midnight

Tags: php, datetime, time

I want to:

- Get the current time
- Add 15 minutes
- Display the new time in H:i:s
- **Know whether the new time went past midnight**

Some examples:

```
Now is 12:00:00
$plus15 is 12:15:00
$pastmidnight = 0

Now is 23:55:00
$plus15 is 00:10:00
$pastmidnight = 1
```

I'd like to use DateTime, but this attempt gives unexpected results:

```
$now = new DateTime(date('H:i:s'));
$now2 = new DateTime(date('H:i:s'));
$now->modify('+15 minutes'); // try "+23 hours", doesn't set $pastmidnight to 1
if($now < $now2){
    $pastmidnight = 1;
}else{
    $pastmidnight = 0;
}
echo $pastmidnight . "->" . $now->format('H:i:s') . "\n";
```

Comment: Your `$now < $now2` condition will **always** be `false`

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but `$now` will **never** be less than `$now2`, so your conditional will never trigger. Even if you added the 15 minutes to `$now2` the logic wouldn't hold, as it would **always** trigger.

To correct this, I would recommend comparing against `strtotime('today midnight')`:

```
$now = new DateTime(date('H:i:s'));
$now->modify('+15 minutes');
$midnight = new DateTime(strtotime('today midnight'));
if ($now > $midnight) {
  $pastmidnight = 1;
}
```

Or set the time of the DateTime to midnight with `setTime(0,0)`:

```
$now = new DateTime(date('H:i:s'));
$now->modify('+15 minutes');
$midnight = new DateTime(date('H:i:s'));
$midnight = $now->setTime(0,0);
if ($now > $midnight) {
    $pastmidnight = 1;
}
else{
    $pastmidnight = 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't think you need `strtotime`. I think `DateTime` can handle the same strings

Comment: Neither of those 2 work for me. I tried with '+23 hours' to get past midnight, but $pastmidnight is always 0

Comment: I got it with @Phil's suggestion: if(!(date_format(new DateTime(date('H:i:s')), 'Y-m-d') == date_format($time, 'Y-m-d'))){